# Detect relation changes on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have 2 models that are linked through a polymorphic association

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  def tags=(ids)
    self.tags.delete_all
    self.tags << Tag.where(id: ids)
  end
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublishablePolymorphicRelationship
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :my_models, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => 'MyModel'
end

tag1 = Tag.create!(...)
tag2 = Tag.create!(...)
my_model = MyModel.create!(...)

my_model.update!(tags: [tag1.id])
```

I created a concern that implements the `after_update` hook so that I can publish the changes on a message queue

However, when the hook is invoked, the changes hash is empty. as well as for the relation

```
module PublishablePolymorphicRelationship
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    after_update    :publish_update

    def publish_update
      model = self.taggable
      puts model.changes
      puts self.changes
      ... # do some message queue publish code
    end
  end
```

end
This would return

```
{}
{}
```

Is there a way I can catch the changes for the polymorphic associations.
Ideally, I would not refer directly to the `tags` model in the concern because I want this concern to be reusable for other models. I am open to adding bits of configuration in the model using the concern though.

**Follow up question**: Is this the right way to do this? I am surprised that the update hook is invoked in the first place. Perhaps I should act on either the creation or deletion hooks instead? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the hacky `MyModel#tags=` setter. There is already a better built in way of doing this by using the `tags_ids=` setter that rails creates for any `has_many` association. It works out of the box with the checkboxes helper as well.

Comment: Also for your concern to work you need to place `after_update    :publish_update` in an `included  do ... end` block. Callbacks and association such are defined in the class definition of a model. But I can't really see why you are using a concern since it does not seem very reusable.

Comment: to simplify the example I hard coded the model with `self.taggable` in practice, I use a class method to set the polymorphic relationship key and I use `self.send(_polymorphic_key)` Does that make sense? Does that improve reusability in your opinion?

Comment: Yes that makes it quite different. You might want to read the docs for ActiveSupport::Concern as you need to remember that code that needs to be evaluated in the context of the class needs to be run when the module is included in the class - not in the module definition.

Comment: That's a good reminder (might serve future reader). Fortunately, I am aware of this.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Basically you're expecting the wrong thing from a join model. The callback does not fire when you are expecting it to unless you are doing something really silly like adding the touch option to your associations (don't do this). See my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never work as you think - `taggings` is just a join model. Rows are only really inserted/deleted indirectly when you add/remove tags to an item. And when that happens there are no changes on either end of the association.

Thus unless you actually manually update the tagging and either end of the associations then `publish_update` will return en empty hash.

If you want to create a resuable component that notifies you when a m2m association is created/destroyed you would do it like so:

```
module Trackable

  included do
    after_create :publish_create!
    after_destroy :publish_destroy!
  end

  def publish_create!
    puts "#{ taxonomy.name } was added to #{item_name.singular} #{ item.id }"
  end

  def publish_destroy!
    puts "#{ taxonomy.name } was removed from #{item_name.singular} #{ item.id }"
  end

  def taxonomy_name
    @taxonomy_name || = taxonomy.class.model_name
  end

  def item_name
    @item_name || = item.class.model_name
  end
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublishablePolymorphicRelationship
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

  alias_attribute :item, :taggable
  alias_attribute :taxonomy, :tag
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublishablePolymorphicRelationship
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true

  alias_attribute :item, :taggable
  alias_attribute :taxonomy, :tag
end
```

Otherwise you need to apply the tracking callbacks to the actual classes you are interested in the changes in.

Comment: You might want to have a look at how  https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity is built